# alarm manager to run activity

Tags: android, android-activity, alarmmanager

I have the following code to set an alarm

```
  @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstance);

            int [] progressVals = getPackets();

            displayList(progressVals, values);

            setAlarm();
        }

private void setAlarm(){
    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
    Queue top = db.getTopQueue();

    if(top != null){
        String p = top.getPacket();
        double timestamp = top.getTimestamp();
        int qNum = top.getExNum();

        Intent intent = new Intent("com.dejalearn.algorithm.AlarmReciever.class");
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(DisplayAllActivity.this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

        Calendar instance = Calendar.getInstance();
        instance.add(Calendar.SECOND, 3);

        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, instance.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
        Toast.makeText(DisplayAllActivity.this, "Start Alarm", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.i("DISPLAY ALL", "ALARM SET UP");
    }
}
```

From this the activity that i try to run from the actual activity running is called AlarmReciever and it extends brodcast receiver however the toast in my alarm receiver never gets run.

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

    public class AlarmReciever extends BroadcastReceiver{

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Log.i("FOUND", "THE MESSAGE");
            try{
                Toast.makeText(context, "made it", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }catch(Exception e){
                Toast.makeText(context, "error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    }
```

How come my new toast is never run. I've looked at multiple examples but nothing seems to be working. I'm not sure what is wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your intent to a valid one:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(DisplayAllActivity.this, AlarmReciever.class);
```

Make sure to add the receiver to the `AndroidManifest.xml` like this:

```
<receiver name=".AlarmReciever" />
```

Comment: I tried that and nothing changed, it still doesn't show the other toast

Comment: did you add your receiver to the AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: it is `.AlarmReceiver` or just `AlarmReceiver`

Comment: with the ".", it's an abbreviation for `<yourfullmanifestpackage>.AlarmReceiver`

Comment: i tried changing it to `.AlarmReciever` but nothing new happened not even in my log cat

Comment: Is your `AlarmReceiver` in your base package?

Comment: it is but its in a different folder in my eclipse so AlarmReceiver is in folder A/ and the activity that calls it is in folder B/

Comment: why would you do that? please try putting both classes into the folder for your package name.

Comment: why would putting, the receiver i want to start, in a different folder like com.a.b and calling it from com.a.c not work, isn't the reference there  when i import the receiver from the right package?

Answer (score 1):

Below is an example that has worked for me in my `Alarm application`:

**myAlarmActivity.class**

```
long startTimeInMilli=setTimeInMilli-System.currentTimeMillis();

Log.d("MYAPP", "set time in milli"+setTimeInMilli);
Log.d("MYAPP", "Total time in milli:"+startTimeInMilli);

Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClass(AlarmMgrActivity.this, MyBroadcastReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(AlarmMgrActivity.this, 234324243/*some random id*/, intent, 0);
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis()
                        + startTimeInMilli, pendingIntent);
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Alarm set in " + startTimeInMilli/1000+ " seconds", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Below is the code for myBroadcastReceiver:

```
public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //Toast.makeText(arg0, "Don't panik but your time is up!!!!.",
          //      Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        // Vibrate the mobile phone
        /*Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) arg0.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        vibrator.vibrate(10000);*/


         AudioManager am= (AudioManager)arg0.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

         if(AlarmMgrActivity.ToMode.equalsIgnoreCase("normal"))
             am.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
         else if(AlarmMgrActivity.ToMode.equalsIgnoreCase("silent"))
             am.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
         else if(AlarmMgrActivity.ToMode.equalsIgnoreCase("vibrate"))
             am.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE);


         Intent i=new Intent();
         i.setClass(arg0, MyService.class);
         arg0.startService(i);
    }

}
```

In the manifest i have registered my broadcast receiver in Manifest.xml as shown below:

```
<application>
.....
.....
<receiver android:name="MyBroadcastReceiver" /> 
.....
.....
</application>
```